# Derivation of formula involving Gamma function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that:

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n+a+b)}{(n+a)(n+b)} = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}$$

whenever $a$ and $b$ are positive.

I know that

$$\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)} = \frac{\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s}s^ads \int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^adt}{\int_0^{\infty}e^{-n}n^{a+b}dn}$$

but am confused as to where to proceed from here... Should I use the product formula for $1/\Gamma$ instead? Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(n+a+b)}{(n+a)(n+b)}
= \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 + \frac{a+b}{n}}{(1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})}
= \prod_{n=1}^\infty 
\frac{
(1 + \frac{a+b}{n})e^{-\frac{a+b}{n}}
}{
\left[ (1+\frac{a}{n})e^{-\frac{a}{n}} \right]
\left[ (1+\frac{b}{n})e^{-\frac{b}{n}} \right]
}\\
= 
\frac{
e^{\gamma(a+b)}\prod_{n=1}^\infty  (1 + \frac{a+b}{n})e^{-\frac{a+b}{n}}
}{
\left[e^{\gamma a}\prod_{n=1}^\infty  (1+\frac{a}{n})e^{-\frac{a}{n}}\right]
\left[e^{\gamma b}\prod_{n=1}^\infty  (1+\frac{b}{n})e^{-\frac{b}{n}}\right]
}
= \frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $x^{(n)}$, denotes the **rising factorial** and
$$ x^{(n)}=x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n-1)=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)} $$
So now
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n+a+b)}{(n+a)(n+b)} $$
$$=\lim_{z\to\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{z}\frac{n(n+a+b)}{(n+a)(n+b)}
$$
$$
= \lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\left[\prod\limits_{n=1}^{z} n\right]\left[\prod\limits_{n=1}^{z} (n+a+b)\right]}{\left[\prod\limits_{n=1}^{z} (n+a)\right]\left[\prod\limits_{n=1}^{z} (n+b)\right]}$$
$$= \lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{z!(a+b+1)^{(z)}}{(a+1)^{(z)}(b+1)^{(z)}}
$$
$$
= \lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(z+1)\frac{\Gamma (a+b+1+z)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}}{\left(\frac{\Gamma(a+1+z)}{\Gamma(a+1)}\right)\left(\frac{\Gamma(b+1+z)}{\Gamma(b+1)}\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(z+1)\Gamma (a+b+1+z)\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+1+z)\Gamma(b+1+z)\Gamma(a+b+1)}
$$
$$
=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(z+1)\Gamma (a+b+1+z)}{\Gamma(a+1+z)\Gamma(b+1+z)}$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Another hint (bit more rigorous perhaps): The Beta Function can be written as
\begin{equation}
B(x,y) = \frac{x+y}{x y} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1+ \dfrac{x y}{n (x+y+n)}\right)^{-1},
\end{equation}
the right hand side of the above formula can be expanded
\begin{eqnarray}
B(x,y) &=& \frac{x+y}{x y} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1+ \dfrac{x y}{n (x+y+n)}\right)^{-1} \\
       &=& \frac{x+y}{x y} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{n(x+y+n)+xy}{n(x+y+n)} \right)^{-1} \\
       &=& \frac{x+y}{x y} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{n(x+y+n)}{xy+n(x+y)+n^{2}}\right) \\
       &=& \frac{x+y}{x y} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{n(x+y+n)}{(n+x)(n+y)}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now; The Beta function has many other forms such as
\begin{equation}
B(x,y)=\dfrac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
\end{equation}
From which a relationship between your left hand side and your right hand side could become readily found once you use properties of the gamma fuction.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use [Euler's infinite product formula for the $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History).

Answer (score 0):

We can use Weierstrass' formula for Gamma function.
Since $\Gamma(a+1) = a\Gamma(a)$,$\Gamma(b+1) = b\Gamma(b)$, $\Gamma(a + b + 1) = (a+b) \Gamma(a + b)$, then $$\frac{\Gamma(a + 1) \Gamma(b + 1)}{\Gamma(a + b + 1)} = \frac{ab \Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{(a+b) \Gamma(a + b)}$$Then according to Weierstrass' formula, we have $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(a + b)} = (a + b) e^{\gamma (a + b)} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}( (1 + \frac{a + b}{n}) e ^ {- \frac{a + b}{n}})$$ And we also have $$\Gamma(a) = \frac{1}{a e^{\gamma a} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} ((1 + \frac{a}{n}) e ^ {- \frac{a}{n}})}$$And similarly we have $$\Gamma(b) = \frac{1}{b e^{\gamma b} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} ((1 + \frac{b}{n})e^{- \frac{b}{n}})}$$ Then we have $$\begin{align} \frac{ab \Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{(a + b) \Gamma(a + b)} & = \frac{e^{\gamma (a + b)} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}( (1 + \frac{a + b}{n}) e ^ {- \frac{a + b}{n}})}{e^{\gamma (a+b)} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} ((1 + \frac{a}{n}) e ^ {- \frac{a}{n}} (1 + \frac{b}{n}) e^{- \frac{b}{n}})} \\ & = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{n + a + b}{n}}{\frac{n + a}{n} \cdot \frac{n + b}{n}} \\ & = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n(n + a + b)}{(n + a) (n + b)} \end{align}$$