Prove $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(n+a+b)}{(n+a)(n+b)} = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}$
Note that you may think it's duplicate but please read the details to see that there is reason for posting this:
My question is $95$% related to this solution (but I noticed this after writing the body here and I upvoted the answer there and made sure there is some difference between my solutions and his solution and reason to post this, otherwise I don't need to, because it's then simply a duplicate)
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4679990/870236
But with a bit difference which is that in the link he did
$$\frac{\Gamma(a + 1) \Gamma(b + 1)}{\Gamma(a + b + 1)} = \frac{ab \Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{(a+b) \Gamma(a + b)}$$
but me I didn't write as him.
And then my work and his work are similar.

Now let's write the question again and my try that is similar to the link but I can't reach even though I checked the steps several times to the degree that I memorize the steps!
Prove that
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(n+a+b)}{(n+a)(n+b)} = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)}$$
$$\Gamma(z) = \frac{1}{ze^{\gamma z}}  \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{z/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)} $$
$$\Gamma(a+1) = \frac{1}{(a+1)e^{\gamma(a+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(a+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+1}{n}\right)}$$
$$\Gamma(b+1) = \frac{1}{(b+1)e^{\gamma(b+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(b+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{b+1}{n}\right)}$$
$$\Gamma(a+b+1) = \frac{1}{(a+b+1)e^{\gamma(a+b+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(a+b+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+b+1}{n}\right)}$$
$$\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)} = 
\frac{\frac{1}{(a+1)e^{\gamma(a+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(a+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+1}{n}\right)} \times 
\frac{1}{(b+1)e^{\gamma(b+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(b+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{b+1}{n}\right)}}
{\frac{1}{(a+b+1)e^{\gamma(a+b+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(a+b+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+b+1}{n}\right)}}$$
Simplify:
$$= \frac{(a+b+1)e^{\gamma(a+b+1)}}{(a+1)(b+1)e^{\gamma(a+b+2)}} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1 + \frac{a+b+1}{n}\right)e^{(a+b+2)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+1}{n}\right)\left(1 + \frac{b+1}{n}\right)e^{(a+b+1)/n}}$$
$$= \frac{(a+b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)e^{\gamma}} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\left(n + a+b+1\right)e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
$$= \frac{(a+b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)e^{\gamma}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty ne^{\frac{1}{n}}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(n + a+b+1\right)}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
$$= e^{-\gamma} \prod_{n=1}^\infty ne^{\frac{1}{n}}
\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(n + a+b+1\right)}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
By changing the index of the second product, we get:
$$= e^{-\gamma} \prod_{n=1}^\infty ne^{\frac{1}{n}}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(n + a+b\right)}{\left(n +a\right)\left(n +b\right)}$$
$$= e^{-\gamma} \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{1}{n}}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\left(n + a+b\right)}{\left(n +a\right)\left(n +b\right)}$$
$$= e^{-\gamma}  e^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\left(n + a+b\right)}{\left(n +a\right)\left(n +b\right)}$$
So I must have
$$e^{-\gamma}  e^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}=1$$
but I am not able of justifying it, because definintion of $\gamma$ is
$$\gamma = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} - \ln(N) \right)$$
What is the problem in my work? or what is the continuation?

You cannot really separate the product if one of your infinite product does not make sense (which is the case of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty n e^{1/n}$). Use the fact that $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ before using the Weierstrass formula for $\Gamma(z)$ and the computation follows.

Because the product I separated is divergent, right? so was that the problem? I am thankful for your kindness to help because no one else helped.

Using How to prove that $e^{-\gamma}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1n\right)e^{-1/n}$ we can fix my solution, my friend told me to use it, but it's strange that users here no one tried to help, anyway, it's no big deal since it's nicer to get the completion by counting on myself:
$$\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+1)} = 
\frac{\frac{1}{(a+1)e^{\gamma(a+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(a+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+1}{n}\right)} \times 
\frac{1}{(b+1)e^{\gamma(b+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(b+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{b+1}{n}\right)}}
{\frac{1}{(a+b+1)e^{\gamma(a+b+1)}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(a+b+1)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+b+1}{n}\right)}}$$
Simplify:
$$= \frac{(a+b+1)e^{\gamma(a+b+1)}}{(a+1)(b+1)e^{\gamma(a+b+2)}} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1 + \frac{a+b+1}{n}\right)e^{(a+b+2)/n}}{\left(1 + \frac{a+1}{n}\right)\left(1 + \frac{b+1}{n}\right)e^{(a+b+1)/n}}$$
$$= \frac{(a+b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)e^{\gamma}} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\left(n + a+b+1\right)e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
$$= \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1n\right)e^{-1/n}\frac{(a+b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\left(n + a+b+1\right)e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
$$= \frac{(a+b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac1n\right)e^{-1/n}\frac{n\left(n + a+b+1\right)e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
$$= \frac{(a+b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)} 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(n + a+b+1\right)}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
$$= 
\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(n + a+b+1\right)}{\left(n +a+1\right)\left(n +b+1\right)}$$
$$= 
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(n\right)\left(n + a+b\right)}{\left(n +a\right)\left(n +b\right)}$$
Math is to be understood not to be memorized without understanding and that we should just use $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$, otherwise the solution will not work.
